# How can I generate unique raffle tickets with a price set

Tags: civicontribute

I'm trying to setup CiviCRM to allow me to sell unique raffle tickets generated in the process of the donation, and provide the purchaser with those raffle tickets and store them into a database for later retrieval for the drawing itself.

This was briefly discussed here ~7 years ago but didn't result in a fully functional solution:  https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=7443.0

Is there a better way to do this with CiviCRM even if I just trigger an external application to generate those ticket numbers?

Comment: Would be useful to have some updated information here on where you're at since the conversation you linked to. E.g. What problems did you run into implementing something like what Lobo posted with hook_altermailParams (I didn't inspect it closely but it looked like he got the basic idea there)? Any other solutions tried and rejected since then? Also... what version of civiCRM are you on what which CMS are you using?